# Upgrading umbraco from 4 to 6

Tags: mysql, umbraco, upgrade

I would like to install Umbraco 6.1.x, but my host suffers from this issue: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-1632

Basically, I can't install 6 due to an incompatibility with MySQL on Linux and Umbraco 6, but I read that I can upgrade from 4.x.x and then upgrade to 6. The question is, how do I do that? I.e. what files do I need to upload and edit such that the database remains, but all umbraco files are version 6?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to the bug report you can install a Umbraco v4.11.x and then upgrade this to v6.1.x and this should work fine.

The downloads are all available here: http://our.umbraco.org/download

However, the easiest way to get Umbraco set up is to use NuGet in Visual Studio. So you could run the following line from the NuGet console:

```
Install-Package UmbracoCms -Version 4.11.10
```

You'll have to use the console for this because if you use the Package manager, it will just install the latest Umbraco package version.

Next, load your site in a browser and configure the database settings. Then upgrade using NuGet again. I find the easiest way to do this is to open the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio, select "Updates", find the Umbraco package and click "Update". This will automatically update all the files for you.

You will then need to load up the site again, at which point it will prompt you to upgrade, and you can just follow the steps in the wizard.

Comment: That's nice. Thanks. However, my host has no nuget access, so I have to do this stuff by ftp.